# DRF Serializer NameError: name 'XYZSerializer' is not defined, Only while fetching in another serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have multiple Serialzers, Independently its working fine. But while fetching it in another serializer it gives NameError: name 'HostGroupSerializer' is not defined

Getting Error Here in this line hostgroup = HostGroupSerializer(many=True, required=False)

```
class MainHostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=HostGroup.objects.all(), many=True)
    hostgroup = HostGroupSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = MainHost
        fields = (
            'host_id', 
            'host_name',
            'inventory',
            'group'
        )  
        depth = 2 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        hostgroup_data = validated_data.pop('hostgroup')
        group = validated_data.pop('group')
        host = MainHost.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for hostgroup in person_data:
            d=dict(group)
            HostGroup.objects.create(host=host, group=d['group'])
        return host

    class Meta:
        model = MainHost
        fields = (
            'host_id', 
            'host_name',
            'inventory',
            'group'
        )
```

HostGroupSerializer.py, its Many2Many Field Table serializer. Created as through field in Parent.

```
class HostGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    host = MainHostSerializer()
    group = MainGroupSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = HostGroup
        fields = (
            'id',
            'host', 
            'group'  
        )  
        read_only_fields = ['host', 'group']
    def create(self, validated_data):
        host_data = MainHost.objects.create(**validated_data.get('host'))
        group_data = MainGroup.objects.create(**validated_data.get('group'))

        conn = HostGroup.objects.create(
            host=host_data, 
            group=group_data
        )
        return conn
```

HostGroup Model

```
class HostGroup(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(MainHost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(MainGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

MainHost Model with Many2Many field

```
class MainHost(models.Model):
    host_id =  models.IntegerField(verbose_name='HOST ID', primary_key=True)
    host_name =  models.CharField(verbose_name='HOST NAME', max_length=512)
    inventory = models.ForeignKey(related_name='inv_ins', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, to='hosts.MainInventory', blank=True, null=True)
    group = models.ManyToManyField(MainGroup, related_name='hostgroups', through ='HostGroup')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass *source* in your `hostgroup = HostGroupSerializer(many=True, required=False)` like this

```
class MainHostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group =serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=HostGroup.objects.all(), many=True)
    hostgroup = HostGroupSerializer(many=True, required=False,source="hostgroup_set")
    class Meta:
        model = MainHost
        fields = (
            'host_id', 
            'host_name',
            'inventory',
            'group'
        )  
        depth = 2
```

Comment: Still same error:     hostgroup = HostGroupSerializer(many=True, required=False, source=hostgroup_set)
NameError: name 'HostGroupSerializer' is not defined

Comment: Please let me know if anybody is having any idea?

Comment: using similar to this but getting NameError: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164616/django-rest-framework-manytomany-relationship-through-intermediate-model

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple Solution: 
HostGroupSerializer has to be defined before MainHostSerializer moving HostGroupSerializer above solves NameError issue